# How i can achieve input checkbox or radio button like this?

Tags: checkbox, radio-button

i want to achieve radio button or check box like this:

[image]

it was on a website [here](https://slicelife.com/restaurants/va/richmond/23223/davinci-richmond/menu?__cf_chl_captcha_tk__=5d364fbe962359cf092c5b3cefb241736927e98b-1587011125-0-ASQ27E7YIM08NgHSbBjX74dt7icNoOct318U_w6lYmBehYyjmE24esFwFTNCujWXP8Dqyw-hb4BFI9kQWpR2FDzPxtl6_ze3HLiW2-Kj3lMeqHrKEb0hU4mzvt5ERCbiQGygYlxuI7ZrRkzrQySSM_mapw2lO86kiJAQwXWgvmqz9SPOJF6jiOt5HSYYmtEdloCBdCO7QXjD9BI7ERdyvUrkec65BM95thSSfXpT4VGPGxzuXWZxOo6YYhs1qY8CM6pt9_tgQroRXfcTc3vVK3L2TcDydZ330Qmlsnj2tgT6WEM2VdsYAMupvt4dQtIls9D0OmUpVde9sOlIx42o-aput9IOylW03HKjaUDAMxlqLbfceF92kjuIskO7_QdKmjWKpiNekPfVz5BYE6HiBCKIzDzwI5ddQP6c3LV31ZmV6gfUgQbgSkCdeA5OuGlE1nBVP34zemwCRQ-K7PYPkUyLkOblEjR335hWkyyrTGj8T-xKCr-kQka3dfTSuxvcp33txohO0wAvUXuDailNC0RDZJgzWPR85N22VhEK8Wj94zmr39ZDdfU9cd9PQUNNjrOtft9OKLuvutxYeiqyywPVmXooR8lZlwCYEjgm5EnJb04aZSN_m2NhVk0wXirQBmBUeOfgfLK8-IvEPrER-Ph4NHh6epLglZjPj12LVR4oG2fMSMwjhMXAJjGxjOSiyasTDsFNFvnxSEAFiqpWiCbbsPifSseUc2hzoTUNQVIudR9JVSisnRyJJ8qTh7muP8i47LY96lqrHMktAegWx8_0r6v4wzfzwFa5G-UBzbZR1pb2PClvU2Phof1DjL4UtA&segment_id=90ba797a-35ac-4bdd-9560-4150ac262493&utm_campaign=partner_websites)

in above link if you choose Cheese Pizza Add > Medium > there you can find input buttons i am looking for.

My code:

```
<div class="boxes_area">
                <div class="main_content">
                    Extra Cheese
                </div>
                <div class="right_side">
                    <div class="right_half_icon_one">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="left_side">
                    <div class="left_half_icon_one">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="full_side">
                    <div class="full_circle">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

With css i achieved:

```
.right_side {
            border: 1px solid;
            border-radius: 50%;
            padding: 5px;
        }

        .modal .modal-header {
            border-bottom: 1px solid;
        }
        .modal .modal-footer {
            border-top: 1px solid;
        }
        .right_half_icon_one img {
            width: 35px;
        }
        .left_half_icon_one img {
            width: 35px;
        }
        .boxes_area {
            margin-top: 5px;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            align-items: center;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }
        .full_circle img {
            width: 35px;
        }
        .right_half_icon_one {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #212a5e;
            border-radius: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .right_half_icon_one::before{
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            content: '';
            left: 18px;
            width: 18px;
            height: 37px;
            background: white;
            border-top-right-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        }
        .left_side {
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .left_half_icon_one {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #212a5e;
            border-radius: 100%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .left_half_icon_one::before{
            position: absolute;
            top: -1px;
            content: '';
            right: 18px;
            width: 18px;
            height: 37px;
            background: white;
            border-top-left-radius: 10px;
            border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        }
        .full_side {
            border: 1px solid;
            padding: 5px;
            border-radius: 100%;
        }
        .full_circle {
            width: 35px;
            height: 35px;
            background: #212a5e;
            border-radius: 50%;
        }
```

but i want those with input and radio box form elements.

Comment: Sorry but it's not very clear to me what you are trying to achieve. Maybe a link to a self contained playground like codepen would help?

Comment: I Apologize my poor explanation, your looking half1, half2, whole, those are input type checkbox or radio button. how i can design them like that and in one row we can only select any one of them. like that how i can do sir..

Comment: and coming to that given url, it was source or original website you can see this kind of popup, for reference purpose i mean how i wan that checkbox looks like.